# Problemas en consultas MySQL 5.7.19

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una duda tengo esta consulta en Mysql en mi instancia local version 8.0.18

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Total DESC) as Ranking,
Nombre_Area, Total
FROM (SELECT Nombre_Area, COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM tickets_rango_fecha
        GROUP BY Nombre_Area
        ORDER BY Total DESC
        LIMIT 20 
) b
```

Y me arroja este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-- Luego tengo la misma consulta pero en otra instancia y me sale el error:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY Total DESC) as Ranking, Nombre_Area, Total FROM (SELECT Nombre_Area, C' at line 1    0.000 sec

Ademas esta instancia tiene la versión 5.7.19.

Mi duda es porque me salta ese error si lo dos manejan la misma base de datos o la estructura tendria que cambiar al ser la versión antigua.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye (como texto, ojalá), el mensaje completo de error. Gracias!

Comment: Ya lo edite ese error me muestra @Alfabravo

Comment: Tienes ese error por que las window functions en MySQL se integraron hasta la versión 8 en adelante: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html por lo tanto con la actual no te servirá

Comment: Y entonces deberia modificar mi consulta, como lo podria hacer ? estaria agradecido si me pudieran orientar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para sustituir el uso de la función ventana [*row number()*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) tendrás que hacer uso de la declaración de una variable en la sesión actual de tu MySQL de esta forma:

```
SET @contador = 0;
```

Posterior cuando hagas tu `SELECT` deberás invocar a dicha función con una sintaxis de:

```
@contador := @contador + 1
```

Lo anterior nos servirá para que por cada fila recuperada de la tabla el valor declarado inicalmente vaya en aumento en razón de 1

Entonces un ejemplo sería así:

```
SET @contador = 0;

SELECT @contador := @contador + 1 as Ranking, columna1, columna2, columnaN
FROM tu Tabla;
```

Trata modificando tu consulta así:

```
SET @contador = 0;

SELECT @contador := @contador as Ranking,
Nombre_Area, Total
FROM (SELECT Nombre_Area, COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM tickets_rango_fecha
        GROUP BY Nombre_Area
        ORDER BY Total DESC
        LIMIT 20 
) b
```

Comment: Me sale el siguiente resultado:                                                                       
         GAF-Creditos y Cobranzas 14
 GAF-Logística y Proyectos 14
 GDC-Procesamiento 14
 GAF-Contabilidad 12
 GAF-Tecnologías de la Información 7
 GDC-PTA-Producción Ate 7
 GOP-Alimentos Balanceados 6
 GOP-Engorde 4
 GAF-Tesorería 4
 GDC-Comercial Canal Moderno 4
 GRH-Seguridad y Salud de Personas 3
 GRH-Bienestar de Personas 2
 GRH-Administración de Personas 2

Comment: En la columna ranking me muestra NULL

Comment: SELECT *contador := *contador as Ranking,
Nombre_Area, Total
FROM (SELECT Nombre_Area, COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM tickets_rango_fecha
        GROUP BY Nombre_Area
        ORDER BY Total DESC
        LIMIT 20 
) b

Comment: No puede poner arroba aqui en los comentarios, pero si estan con arroba

Comment: Ya lo hice amigo

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo !!